# Get resource from jar

Tags: java, resources, jar

I have jar with files:

```
myJar/res/endingRule.txt
myJar/wordcalculator/merger/Marge.class
```

In Marge.java I have code:

```
private static final String ENDINGS_FILE_NAME = "res/endingRule.txt";
....
InputStream inputStream  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ENDINGS_FILE_NAME);
.....
```

But after this inputStream is null. How to work with resources? Why null?

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but your looking for 'res/endingRule.csv' which isn't in your jar, according to the first lines of your question..

Comment: sorry, I fixed code. endingRule.txt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To retrieve the file inside the jar, use:

```
private static final String ENDINGS_FILE_NAME = "/res/endingRule.txt";
...
InputStream is = getClass( ).getResourceAsStream(ENDINGS_FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary when using `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` though - that wouldn't require a leading slash.

Comment: For all other people who come across this, CASE SENSITIVITY MATTERS with file names. At least it did on Windows 7 with JRE 6.

Comment: For me it didn't work when I start with '/' it started working when I removed it and write it like this: URL myUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/endingRule.txt");

Answer (score 6):

Your name looks wrong - incorrect extension *and* the wrong kind of slash:

```
private static final String ENDINGS_FILE_NAME = "res/endingRule.txt";
```

Comment: @Victoria: I don't think it was the lack of a leading slash that was the problem, if you're *genuinely* calling `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` rather than just `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon your this additional information! Helped me 2 1,5 years later! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is being interpreted as an escape character rather than directory separator.  File name is also off.  Try:

```
private static final String ENDINGS_FILE_NAME = "res/endingRule.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
private static final String ENDINGS_FILE_NAME = "res\\endingRule.txt";
```