# How to get a txt file from a jar in tomcat7

Tags: java, jar, tomcat7

I have a `txt` file. I have packaged it in a zip and a jar, using `jar cf0...`. I have tried both in an effort to get this to work.

```
models.zip/models.jar
 |
 |_subfolder
     |
     |_MyFile.txt
```

In some code I have...

```
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

I have tried setting path to...

```
MyFile.txt
/MyFile.txt
/subfolder/MyFile.txt
classpath:/subfolder/MyFile.txt
models.zip/subfolder/MyFile.txt
models.jar/subfolder/MyFile.txt
models.zip!/subfolder/MyFile.txt
models.jar!/subfolder/MyFile.txt
```

I have also tried putting the `jar/zip` in `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib`.

None of this works, `in` is always null.

And just so you know, when I put MyFile.txt in WEB-INF/classes I can get it fine.

Please provide a tried and tested answer! Please dont just copy and paste code from another answer.

Comment: I take it your models.{jar,zip} is not in the classpath?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get resource from jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831845/get-resource-from-jar)

Comment: Is there an underscore before the filename? If so you need to include that in the path.

Comment: just to be sure, can you add exact output of "jar tvf models.jar" ?

Comment: fge - I believe lib and classes are both in tomcat classpath.
triton - no underscore.

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of your app? and if you can the contents of the jar?

Comment: @TedTrippin "I believe lib and classes are both in tomcat classpath" <-- I was talking about your models.* file here. If it were in a classpath, were a zip file and had the extention `.jar`, `.getResourceAsStream()` would have found the file.

Comment: Yes, when I do getResourceAsStream("models.jar") it returns the jar.

Comment: @TedTrippin then maybe the jar does not contain the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like a plonker! Problem was having models.jar in both the lib AND the classes folder. It should be in just the lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream  ("/subfolder/MyFile.txt");
```

and put your jar file in WEB-INF/lib/

EDIT: you should trust your own code, this is a fragment from a running webapp of mine.
Class is in package "it.sft.utils.props" and the relative property file is packaged via ant int the very same folder of the very same jar. This works flawlessly.

In your specific scenario, probably you don't have the jar in your classpath

```
 private void loadFromProperties() throws IOException {
            if (currencies == null) {
                currencies = new Properties();
                InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream  ("/it/sft/utils/props/currencies.props");
            if (is != null) {

                currencies.load(is );

                for (String key : currencies.stringPropertyNames()) {
                    String value = currencies.getProperty(key);
                    try {
                        String [] tmp = value.split(",");
                        String code = tmp[0];
                        int decs = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
                        String text = tmp[2];
                        Logger.getLogger(CurrencyResolver.class).debug("Adding " + key + " with code " + code + " [" + text + "]");
                        storeValutaIso4217(new ValutaIso4217(key, code, decs, text));
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // Ignore
                        Logger.getLogger(CurrencyResolver.class).warn("Cannot handle " + key + " >" + value + "<");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or are you by chance running it from some kind of IDEs (NetBeans or Eclipse) ?

Just for being paranoid: the jar file is actually readable by the tomcat run user, isn't it ?

Comment: -1 I requested dont just copy and paste. And no, that doesnt work.

Comment: @TedTrippin strange, it's been running in production on a jBoss AS server for about 2 years.

Comment: @kutschkem I agree with you.

Comment: Just running under tomcat as my own user on windows. If I deploy the text file on its own then no problem, only when its in a jar/zip. And jar tvf does show the file.

Comment: @TedTrippin are you deploying the application as a war, as an ear or as a directory ? code is right, and IT has to work.

Comment: "IT has to work" , you're right. Problem was having the jar in both classes AND lib :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the trailing `/` in `/subfolder/MyFile.txt`.

The spring [ClassPathResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) class uses almost the same operation you are using, but the [javadoc states plainly](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#ClassPathResource%28java.lang.String%29):

> Create a new ClassPathResource for ClassLoader usage. A leading slash
>   will be removed, as the ClassLoader resource access methods will not
>   accept it.

So, without spring it would be:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("subfolder/M‌​yFile.txt");
```

Also, your jar must be put in `WEB-INF/lib` or if you want to put the text file alone, put it in `WEB-INF/classes/subfolder/`.

If you are using spring (my guess because you are using the pseudo url classpath:) is use directly this:

```
InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("subfolder/MyFile.txt").getInputStream();
```

Comment: I don't agree, I've always loaded properties files located in the same source of relative pojos using the leading "/", thou I never used Spring

Comment: As stated, I've tried putting it in the lib and classes folders. No, not using spring, just trying different examples I have googled.

Comment: Can you thy with `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("subfolder/MyFile.txt");`

Comment: @TedTrippin mmm... then with trailing slash? LoL