# Unable to read input file from bin

Tags: java, file, properties, filenotfoundexception

Errr guys, I wrote some code to read a simple input file in Java, everything works perfectly fine, however after the code is checked-in and when others try to run it, their binary couldn't find the file (eventhough the file is RIGHT THERE in their bin folder)!

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\blah\bin\com\common\PackageRFCs.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

So in my workspace, I have the these structure and files:

```
com.test.test.java
com.common.Utility.java
com.common.PackageRFCs.properties
```

In my **test.java**, I am trying to read the properties file this way:

```
Class<com.common.Utility> dummy = com.common.Utility.class;
String propURI = dummy.getPackage().getName().replace('.','/') + "/PackageRFCs.properties";
String filepath = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(propURI).getFile();
...
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
// do some read line stuff here
```

The above code work perfectly fine under my Eclipse, but failed when others tried to run it. I thought maybe i had some dangling file in my bin, so i did a Project > Clean, and i am still able to run it perfectly fine... I also tried cleaning the other user's workspace as well, and they still couldn't read the file... WTF is going on?

I can't reproduce the problem on my end.

Comment: check that the file is actually in the classpath by running the .class file on the commando prompt (check my answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238699/how-to-get-a-txt-file-from-a-jar-in-tomcat7/14238813#14238813 is pretty similar)

Comment: Have you tried writing a manual path to the file instead of using ClassLoader ?

Comment: Yea, I tried a couple of different ways to read the file, actually went through 3 different questions here on StackOverflow. @Ian Roberts below solved the problem, I have to use **getResourceAsStream**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a URL from `getResource()` you don't need to convert it to a filepath and open that with a `FileReader` (which won't work anyway, as the result of `URL.getFile()` isn't a native file path, it's simply a substring of the original URL).  Just use `.openStream()` or call `get{System}ResourceAsStream()` in the first place

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(propURI), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

(I've assumed ISO-8859-1 encoding because the file is named `.properties` and this is the standard encoding for Java property files, but if that is wrong then change the encoding to match the file)

But given the structure you've spelled out, it would be more robust to use

```
Utility.class.getResourceAsStream("PackageRFCs.properties")
```

which handles the package-to-path mapping for you automatically, as well as being able to handle cases when your classes are loaded by a classloader other than the system classloader.

Comment: Wow, so much cleaner. Using getResourceAsStream works perfectly now! Very nice explanation on the getResources(), I wish i can give you a couple more thumbs up. Thanks Ian!