# Loading Properties File from Static Context

Tags: java, properties, resources

I've recently found myself faced with a pretty interesting issue. I have a `properties` file in my application, and I am attempting to load it from a static context. The `properties` file is loaded from a class `Image`, which is a static class. In Eclipse it works fine, but when I tried to export it as a JAR, it's obviously not worked.

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream(new  File(Images.class.
getClassLoader().
getResource("config.properties").
toString())));
```

This is the line I've tried to use already, however when I try to run the program, it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.Images.loadImageFiles(Images.java:47)
    at views.World.<init>(World.java:55)
    at views.World.main(World.java:40)
```

I am somewhat at a loss here, so my question is:

How do I load a resource from a static context, and more importantly, do I need to register the file as a resource before I do this?

**Edit**

After some searching, I've established that it is the `getResource` method that is returning `null`. My big question now, I guess, is why!? My file Structure is as follows:

```
Project
        src
             controllers <-- This is where the Images class is.
             models
             views
             img
             doc
             config.properties <-- This is the file I want.
```

I'm not entirely sure how that will help but I'm stuck for answers.

Comment: Does `getResource("/config.properties")` works ?

Comment: No, tried that several times. @NoobUnChained

Comment: When you access files inside a jar, you need to change the way you get them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831845/get-resource-from-jar. See the answer of @davmos.

Comment: Note that the problem is not calling the resource from a static context but that it is inside the jar.

Comment: Agreed. Apologies. After three hours my mind is becoming less and less capable. Davmos' answer has got it to load the images initially. Now I have a load of paths, and I have no clue how to read them! IT just gets better :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the properties file in the same directory as the class and use the [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) method instead. It will return an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) so there is no need to construct the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). It will also continue to work if you package your classes in a jar...

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.load(Images.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

Or from a static context:

```
prop.load(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

Comment: There is no getClass() method when you are in a static context. What object do you call getClass() on?