# Package plink with jar

Tags: java, eclipse, package, putty, plink

I have written a code (Java using eclipse Juno) which uses plink (C: installation) to connect to a remote server.

```
String command = "C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\plink -load session-name -l login -pw password";
Process p = runtime.exec (command);
```

Is there anyway I can safely export it (putty/plink) along with the jar file. This is so as there would not be any need of separate installation. I would also have to alter the code to call plink locally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jar utility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) that comes with Java SDK to package putty executables to your application jar file.

Upon installation you [can extract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831906/784540) your exe file to a folder. And later [call it from your code](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/).

Comment: I have packaged my plink executables along the jar file (using export). However, I can run it from the eclipse console but the exported jar does not recognize the plink.exe location. I cross verfified it to be fine. Says, "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the specified file".

Comment: PS: I copied PuTTY setup into a res folder within the project. Thanks.

Comment: @AryA Your java code is unable to find path to the putty executable. Provide correct path to your executable before launching it.

Comment: As I see now, when I gave the path as "res/plink", the application looks for res folder in same location where .jar is located. I can make it work if I paste my "res/plink" in this place, but I need to call it from within the jar file which is packaged. Let me know if I need to make it more clear.

Comment: @AryA it is not possible to call an executable packaged into an archive/jar-file. Anyway you have to extract this executable and all files it depends on to a temporary folder and only then launch it.

Answer (score -2):

I am using the below code in plink.

"C:\Users\YXS8699\Desktop\Desktop\ansi165\x86\ansicon.exe \"C:\Progra~1\PuTTY\plink.exe\" ";

It was working fine.

Now when we run the plink command to connect WYSE50 terminal. I am facing the below issue

Command Prompt: 
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" CPHPQPU1.homedepot.com -l dbxd -pw 123summer -t WYSE50

Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:

Now it is not working fine. Please give me some inputs.

Regards,
Yellappa

Comment: please ask a new question