# Include text file in Eclipse JAR export?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar

I am using a `FileInputStream` to read from a `File` object. My program is able to read the text file when run in the Eclipse IDE, but not when it is run as a JAR file.

I am exporting it as a `JAR file` and not a `Runnable JAR file`, and I know that the text file is already included in the JAR file because I extracted it to check.

This is what my file structure looks like:
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to access your file?  If you're trying to read it from the file system it won't find it inside the jar.  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831845/get-resource-from-jar) may be helpful

Comment: I am accessing my file as a stream like this in one of my source files: `new FileInputStream(new File("./learnaboutfonts.txt")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to put your `learnaboutfonts.txt` inside `src` folder(not inside package) and read file in source code like the following:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext().getResource("classpath:learnaboutfonts.txt");
InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

And you can use `br` as you want to use. Happy Coding.

Comment: Do not forget to add spring-context jar in your build path(spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar).

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/learnaboutfonts.txt");
```

Note that the trick is using the leading "/" properly. If you don't put the leading /, then it searches for the file in the package of the class its invoked from.

Comment: Probably a good idea. It is assigning a null value to `input` though, is there any reason that could be why?

Comment: for the above code to work, the file learnaboutfonts should be in the root of the jar. is it?

Comment: Your answer is correct. Actually, the text file is supposed to be in the source folder, not the root folder, and I apologize. +1  :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you access your file? You maybe need a relative file path like "./mytext.txt").

Use this pattern:

```
InputStream is = new getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                        "/text.txt");
```

Test to include your text-file in your package of your class where you want to access the file.

Comment: This does not work. I am getting a null value for `is`.

Comment: using "new Object()" for this is not funny.

Comment: I've copied it from a static context. Yes, ist better to use getClass() directly:).