# How to locate fxml files so my JavaFX project runs easily on any PC?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

[image]

EDIT: My code works fine and well on my PC. I have no issues with loading my own FXML files. I want it to work on other PCs as well.

Ignoring the error in the console, is this a bad way of locating my fxml files? For some reason, this won't run on another PC because it can't locate the fxml files, eventhough I haven't provided any URL that starts from a folder name related to my PC only.

What I mean is that all fxmlloader urls start from the codingWizard package and then continues on from there. Why doesn't this work on another PC? On my friends PC when it was on the Desktop, it said it couldn't find the location: C:/Users/HisPC/Desktop/..../codingWizard/.... and so on.

If this is the wrong way of packaging the fxml files, what would be the correct way so that I can provide a URL for the FXMLLoader that just works on any other PC without needing adjustments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get resource from jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831845/get-resource-from-jar)

Comment: Not even close? The correct answer involves getting the answer with a resource stream, (getResourceAsStream()) which is not something I want. Also this is not a jar file. Also the guy couldn't load his own .txt file while I can load my own fxml files. It just doesn't work on other PCs. Read the thread for the love of god.

Comment: Access your resources (not only FXML files) as *resource*. Put them in a separate folder (usually `${project_loc}/src/main/resources}`) which is set as "source folder" in your IDE. Then you can access it as `getClass().getResource("/path/below/resourceFolder/my.fxml")`

Comment: The solution didn't work. I've located them at src/main/resources/somename.fxml and called it with getClass().getResource("/src/main/resources/somename.fxml"); I also tried "src/main/resources/....", "/main/resources/....", "main/resources/....", "/resources/...." and "resources/...."

Comment: did you also try `getClass().getResource("/somename.fxml");`?

Comment: BTW: you already use `/src` as a source folder. Therefore you must use a different top folder.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Where would the file be located in that case? An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your FXML files are resources which most likely do not change after you released your program. You should access them via `getClass().getResource("/somename.fxml")`;

To enable this access you must add the location of that files to the projects *classpath*

Best way to do so is to switch your projects directory structure to the *standard project directory layout* as it is suggested by the *apache* project: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

You configure you IDE to use 
`${project_loc}/src/main/java`and 
`${project_loc}/src/main/resources` as "source folder" (removing  "source folder"-property from `${project_loc}/src` )

After this change you can access the file `${project_loc}/src/main/resources/my.fxml` with this code:

```
getClass().getResource("/my.fxml");
```

Your IDE will include all files in `${project_loc}/src/main/resources` into the delivery artifact.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I managed to work it better in my application by putting all my CSS and FXML files into a folder called /src/codingWizard/resources and then initializing that folder as the *resources* but it still doesn't work when I run it from another PC.

Comment: I'm an idiot actually. It always worked. I forgot to send the image libraries I used in my project that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. Timothy Truckle's answer works. My original code would probably work as well, I was being an idiot and forgot to transfer the image folder I had in my main PC.

That's why the FXML folders were giving an error and saying Invalid URL or resource not found. All along I thought it was referring to the FXML file location but it was referring to the image location.

Edit: My original code works fine provided I include the images.